# Inject common attribute from spring configuration file to every test class

Tags: spring, testng

I have small clarification regarding the spring injection. I'm writing the test for services. Every Test class has a common attribute called "tenantId". Can I inject that attribute through spring configuration file.I don't want to add every test class to the spring configuration file, Is there a way to that?

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:applicationContext-service-test.xml"})
public class ApplicationServiceTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    TenantBasedSessionFactory tenantBasedSessionFactory;


    @Autowired
    private ApplicationService applicationService;
    private String tenantId = "tenantId"; // I want this to inject from applicationContext-service-test.xml 
    private Session session;
}
```

Spring configuration file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Use @Transaction annotations for managing transactions  -->
    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Activates scanning of @Autowired -->
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <!-- Activates scanning of @Service and @Repository -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="lk.gov.elg"/>

    <!-- JDBC property file -->
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <!--<value>classpath:test.jdbc.properties</value>-->
                <value>jdbc.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!--<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"-->
    <!--p:driverClassName="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" p:url="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test"-->
    <!--p:username="sa" p:password="" />-->


    <!-- create database connection pool -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <!--<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">-->
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
        <property name="maxActive" value="100"/>
        <property name="maxWait" value="1000"/>
        <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true"/>
        <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="lk.gov.elg.orm.model"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>
                hibernate.dialect=${hibernate.dialect.test}
                hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
                hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
                hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tenantBasedSessionFactory" class="lk.gov.elg.orm.dao.impl.TenantBasedSessionFactoryImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
</beans>
```

Thank you in advance 
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can create a common superclass for all your tests to inject there your `tenantId`. With this, you will only have to inject only once and `tenandId` will be available to all your desired classes.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, yes I could do it in that way, I want to know whether it could be done in Spring